# Record Edit for custom metadata

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-metadata

Is it possible to use `lightning-record-edit-form` in LWC for custom metadata types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMDT "records" are considered metadata, not normal record data, and as such, can only be updated through a deployment or package upgrade. You therefore would need to write your own custom edit form so you can do a metadata deploy.